# C conditional expression in _Generic

Tags: c, generics, conditional-operator

i have a simple question:
why does gcc say that i have a mismatch at the two lines?

```
WARNING: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression
```

```c
#define TEST(v) _Generic((v),   
    _Bool:          (v) ? "true" : "false", \
    char*:          (v) ? (v) : "null",  /* <- WARNING */ \
    const char*:    (v) ? (v) : "null",  /* <- WARNING */ \
    default:        (v))

    _Bool s = FALSE;
    printf(TEST(s));
    printf("\n");

    char *c = "string";
    printf(TEST(c));
    printf("\n");

    char *x = NULL;
    printf(TEST(x));
    printf("\n");
```

EDIT:

```c
    float f = 5;
    printf(TEST(f));
    printf("\n");
```

this example will cause an

```
ERROR: type mismatch in conditional expression
```

why is float or double so different at this point?

Comment: It'd be nice if you could turn this into a [mcve], a complete source file that someone can copy and paste into a compiler and get the same error.  I'd like to help, but it's too annoying to have to take this code and wrap it in a function, remember which header files to include, etc, etc, before I can even test it.

Comment: At a glance, the last example with `float` seems that it will become `printf(f)` which is obviously no good, but I don't think that's the cause of the error you're seeing.

Comment: yes you are right ... all branches will be checked: (bool) ? (bool) : (char*) could be the problem

Comment: `char*: (v) ? (v) : "null"` -->. `char*: (v) ? (char*)(v) : "null"` may reduce the problem.